# how can I propage the content a of publishing site subweb to a root web of another farm site collection?

Tags: publishing-site, content-deployment

I have two SP Farm 2010 (not same domain) with standard licence

- intranet
- extranet

Both farms have a publishing portal.

I'd like to have the content of the extranet portal to be part of the intranet (i.e. a subsite of the intranet portal)

- intranet home

  - intranet area1
  - intranet area2
  - extranet area

    - extranet subarea 1
    - extranet subarea 2
- extranet home (exact clone, in term of content, of extranet area of intranet)

  - extranet subarea 1
  - extranet subarea 2

What are my options ? Fortunately, extranet home can be read only (everything done in intranet).

I think that I can't use the content deployment features, because I'm not cloning a site, but a subweb (and its descendant).

Maybe export-spweb and import-spweb can works, but isn't there any side effect ?

Comment: Have you considered publishing highlights from the extranet to your intranet? On low volume sites, it might even make sense to do that manually. In my experience, replicating content is often confusing, both for the replicator and the viewer.

Comment: what are you calling an highlight? a "view" of remote content (rss maybe) ?

Comment: Yes. RSS would be a great fit for this if what you really want is syndication and not duplication.

Comment: Isn't it just an option to make the extranet available in the navigation panel of your intranet? Or do you need to present the data in another way to your users on the intranet? 
There are a lot of solutions here, but a lot may not be possible due to some requirements ;) If the extranet-design may be showed in your intranet, the solutions gets easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Export and Import work, but yes, there are side effects. Another issue you will face is the relative URLs will be messed up. Unfortunately, this is also the case if you use content deployment. Content deployment would be my best suggestion, however, the content that is published needs to be at the same level in order for relative URLs to work. YOu could consider using a host header site collection to publish from the internal site to the external, but it would still be a site collection.

Comment: Lori has a good point with the relative links. You could write something custom to fix them up or maybe buy a third party toool, but either way, you may not end up with 100% solution. If you do go with Export and Import, the flags you pass are important. In my experience, export-spweb with -IncludeVersions All and Import-SPWeb with -IncludeUserSecurity get most of what I need besides relative links.